# Send in form if button pressed

Tags: html, forms, button

I have two buttons in my form (that JS is listening to so I can show certain fields in the form).

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="Distance" id="one_way_button">Distance & Time</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="Distance" id="stored_button">Stored Address</button>
</div>
```

I would like to actually send which button is pressed in the form post data. We are using ruby on rails, if that matters. Not sure what I need to do to change my html to actually send which button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the button name in hidden input before submit

```
function fnSubmitForm(obj)
{
    document.getElementById("ButtonName").value = obj.value

    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

onclick to call your the above function

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
<input type="hidden" id="ButtonName" name="ButtonName" value="" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="Distance" id="one_way_button" onclick="fnSubmitForm(this)" value="Distance & Time" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="Distance" id="stored_button" onclick="fnSubmitForm(this)" value="Stored Address" />
</div>
```

Comment: Amended the answer, thanks @CameronAziz for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `event.target` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property to know which button is clicked.

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.btn-group'); //assuming div has no id
parent.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if(evt.target.id === 'one_way_button') {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do other thing
    }
}, true);
```